# Open qtconsole automatically when starting single jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, qtconsole

Looking to have a qtconsole open automatically when I start an individual Jupyter notebook. I usually will Anaconda prompt with 'jupyter notebook', click to start a notebook, then open a second Anaconda prompt window and type 'jupyter qtconsole --existing'

Is there a way to avoid typing this every time I open a single notebook?

I figure there has to be some way via the notebook.json file in .jupyter\nbconfig, or something along those lines.